# uitableview set on viewcontroller then delegate datasource by inspecter according other post i tried viewcontroller view uitableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datasource, xcode4.6, ios6.1

I am trying simple things in view controller drag `UITableView` define

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> 
{     
     IBOutlet UITableView* tv;     
} 
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView * tv; 

#import "ViewController.h" 
@interface ViewController ()  
@end  
@implementation ViewController 
@synthesize tv;
```

when I try to run the app it crashes. I read same related issue and I am trying to select viewcontroller then in view set `UITableviewcontroller` but I still get the issue .

Comment: connect IBOutlet,delegate and datasource in XIB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this images may be it'l helps you,

1.connect IBoutlet

[image]

2.connect Delegate and Datasource

[image]

Comment: Thank for replaying my question

Comment: ya its helpful Thank you once again